# How to use Foreman with subfolders and nested Gemfiles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundler, foreman, procfile

I'm working on a large project with a UI, a Rails API, and some other Rails/Ruby based services located in a monorepo. I'm trying to set up some Rake tasks around Foreman at the root of the project to start up the project in development mode.

The root of the repo contains a Gemfile with Foreman and Rake and a Procfile:

```
rails-api: sh -c 'cd ./rails-api && bundle && bundle exec rails server'
```

The `rails-api` folder is just a standard Rails 5 API app with its own Gemfile.

When running `foreman start` from the repo root, this is the following output:

```
11:30:10 factory-api.1 | started with pid 38593
11:30:11 factory-api.1 | Using rake 12.3.0
11:30:11 factory-api.1 | Using bundler 1.16.1
11:30:11 factory-api.1 | Using colorize 0.8.1
11:30:11 factory-api.1 | Using dotenv 2.2.1
11:30:11 factory-api.1 | Using thor 0.19.4
11:30:11 factory-api.1 | Using foreman 0.84.0
11:30:11 factory-api.1 | Bundle complete! 4 Gemfile dependencies, 6 gems now installed.
11:30:11 factory-api.1 | Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
11:30:11 factory-api.1 | bundler: failed to load command: rails (/Users/matthew/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/rails)
11:30:11 factory-api.1 | Gem::Exception: can't find executable rails for gem railties. railties is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile?
11:30:11 factory-api.1 |   /Users/matthew/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:458:in `block in replace_bin_path'
11:30:11 factory-api.1 |   /Users/matthew/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:478:in `block in replace_bin_path'
11:30:11 factory-api.1 |   /Users/matthew/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/rails:23:in `<top (required)>'
11:30:11 factory-api.1 | exited with code 1
11:30:11 system        | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

As you can see, it's bundling the root Gemfile. Manually bundling from the subfolder works just fine. Even manually executing `sh -c 'cd ./rails-api && bundle && bundle exec rails server'` works just fine.

I've also tried throwing a `pwd` in the Procfile line and it is returning the subfolder, but `bundle` is still running in the root.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem, and it's due to a piece I didn't think was super important but left out of the original queston.

Foreman was being started from the bundle from a Rake task in the root of the repo:

```
exec('bundle exec foreman start -p Procfile.dev')
```

Calling it this way does use Foreman from the bundle, but Bundler takes over everything. I changed this line to:

```
Bundler.clean_system('foreman start -p Procfile.dev')
```

And everything seems to be working fine.